# Would you ever use or suggest a midrange or mainframe for a new project?

Tags: mainframe

Calling all system admins!

Would you ever consider starting to use a IBM midrange / mainframe / power series / HP Integrety server instead of x86/x64 for a "new" project ?

Does anyone even care about these types of platforms anymore ?

What are your thoughts ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mainframe-type and Power systems are still very relevant. x86/x86_64 environments are typically built to run 'reasonably' reliably with redundancy built into the software layer.

Mainframe/Power systems are built with *huge* RAS features - properly managed, they are not going down. Another advantage is the massive <s>virtualization</s> partitioning that they can handle - you can have thousands of Linux or AIX instances running in parallel on a single high end Power server.

Yes, they are still being sold and deployed for new projects.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - depending on what the project is.

Linux on z-Series, for example, could be a strong contender for cloud computing.

Comment: +1 for linux on system z .  *nobody* does virtualization like mainframes

Comment: IBM's been in the news on this just very recently, too: antitrust probing: http://news.google.com/news?q=ibm%20antitrust

Comment: yeah, the old school mainframe stuff IBM has going is a total racket.  IFLs are the only way to go.

Comment: it's only a racket, though, because nobody else does mainframes (really) anymore - but I don't see that as IBM's fault, personally :)

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to tell which platform is right for a generic "new project".

It totally depends on what the "new project" is.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of platform is often dependent on the availability of software. There are a number of manufacturing, point-of-sale, statistical analysis and scientific applications available only on midrange/mainframe.

Software and usage requirements should dictate the hardware used.